# What is the most common way to do authentication in rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I need to do authentication in rail3 with standard sign up/login/forgot password functionality.  Is there a plugin or something that most people use for this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not sure what the most common method is - but certainly a very popular gem is 'Devise', by Plataformatec: http://github.com/plataformatec/devise

I've tried a few auth gems and for me, it was the simplest to setup and modify to my needs. It has built in password recovery, as well as account confirmation (if required) and a few other very handy features.

Comment: I used authlogic for some time and recently moved to devise. I can surly recommend devise over authlogic, as it is lot more advanced and much more future complete.

Comment: Agree completely: devise is much easier to get started with if you have nothing, and integrates very nice into rails3.

Answer (score 2):

The most popular is definately authlogic. I would agree with theTRON though, devise is the way to go.

Comment: It does work with rails3, i described it here: http://www.dixis.com/?p=352 But! devise offers more straight out of the box.